# SQL запрос к базе данных с двумя переменными и таблицами в 3-НФ

Tags: sql

С SQL так плотно не работал, и задание вызвало кучу вопросов, с первым вроде разобрался:

В бд сервера корпоративного антивируса содержится информация об обнаруженных вирусных заражениях, она включает название вируса, время обнаружения, путь до зараженного/вредоносного файла, статус ("вылечен", "удален", "перемещен в карантин"), а также имя ПК, на котором зафиксировано заражение. Введено понятие "вирусной эпидемии". Эпидемией считается ситуация, когда в течение времени T зафиксировано более N заражений определенным вирусом. Требуется:

- описать структуру БД (при условии, что БД находится в 3-НФ);
- написать запрос, выводящий следующие данные об эпидемии: название вируса, количество заражений, статус.

С первым вроде все понятно, 4 таблицы, вроде как 3НФ получилось?:

```
1. computers (id PRIMARY KEY, name)
2. viruses (id PRIMARY KEY, name)
3. statuses (id PRIMARY KEY, name)
4. detections (id, path, date, computer_id FOREIGN KEY computers(id), virus_id FOREIGN KEY viruses(id), status_id FOREIGN KEY status(id)
```

```sql
SELECT viruses.name, COUNT(detections.id)
FROM detections, viruses
WHERE detections.virus_id = viruses.id
GROUP BY detections.virus_id
HAVING COUNT(detections.id) > 1
```

А вот разбить их еще по статусу пока не сильно получается.

```sql
SELECT v.name AS virus, s.name AS status, COUNT(d.id) AS detects
FROM detections d
JOIN viruses v ON d.virus_id = v.id
JOIN statuses s ON d.status_id = s.id
GROUP BY v.id, s.id
```

Вроде работает.

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как не соответствующего теме, потому что работа за автора.

Comment: Решать за меня не надо, я не могу понять только как сделать выборку не перебирая известные вирусы через внешний скрипт.
А сделать выборку плана count(detections.virus_id) > N

Comment: Ну так покажите что Вы пытались сделать сами

Comment: А почему тогда ваш вопрос не содержит ровно одну конкретную проблему?

Comment: Дописал то, что получилось пока.

Comment: у вас поля v.name AS virus, s.name AS status не участвуют в группировке или не заданы агрегатные ф-ии для них

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Решил данный вопрос:

```
SELECT v.name AS virus, s.name AS status, COUNT(d.id) AS detects
FROM detections d
JOIN viruses v ON d.virus_id = v.id
JOIN statuses s ON d.status_id = s.id
WHERE DATE.min > d.date < DATE.max
GROUP BY v.id, s.id
HAVING COUNT(d.id) > N
```